# best_params_ sklearn invalid syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

При попытки воспроизвести код:

```
parameters = {'max_depth': 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'max_leaf_nodes': 25, 50, 75, 100, 
125, 150, 175, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
clf = GridSearchCV(lasso_model, parameters, scoring='mean_squared_error', cv=3)
clf.fit(X, y)
```

Появляется ошибка

```
File "<ipython-input-3-25ffafcf2061>", line 1
parameters = {'max_depth': 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 'max_leaf_nodes': 25, 50, 75, 100, 
125, 150, 175, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас ошибка в правильном заполнение словаря

```
parameters = {'max_depth': [4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 'max_leaf_nodes': [25, 50, 75, 100,
              125, 150, 175], 'min_samples_leaf': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Кроме очевидной синтаксической ошибки, на которую уже указал @Twiss в своем ответе - у вас присутствует логическая:

У алгоритма [Lasso](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Lasso.html) нет таких параметров, скорее всего вы имели ввиду один из алгоритмов, реализующих [деревья решений](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.tree) или [случайного леса решений](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html).